# Exporting to table record to .docx from PHP application

Tags: php, docx

I have a table that filters records that has more than 4000 records (rows). The code exports the table with total summary to word (.docx). But after exporting 2622 rows it stops. I tried to increase the capacity of Xampp but still not exporting all the rows to word.

This is the PHP code the phprad generates for exporting the code.

```
<?php $export_word_link = $this->set_current_page_link(array('format' => 'word')); ?>

<a class="dropdown-item export-link-btn" data-format="word" href="<?php print_link($export_word_link); ?>" target="_blank">
  <img src="<?php print_link('assets/images/doc.png') ?>" class="mr-2" /> WORD
</a>
```

This is the error I get

> PHP Warning:  DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML(): Entity: line 68183: parser error : xmlSAX2Characters: huge text node in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\system\BaseView.php on line 743

This is line C:\xampp\htdocs\project\system\BaseView.php on line 743

```
$fragment->appendXML($html);
```

Any help please?

Comment: Why is the question edited and the answer is deleted?